# Deployment of a worker service throws Error 1503

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, worker

I'm trying to register service and to start it for my .net core (.net 5) worker service.

Error that I have is popping out, when I click on `Start` for newly created service.

Application was published in release mode, with following characteristics:

*Configuration: Release | Any CPU,
Target framework: net5.0,
Deployment mode: Framework-dependent,
Target runtime: win-x64*

My server is x64 windows server machine.

This is the code of my Program and Worker classes:

[Code Preview](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mz52xJT5m4/)

I just wanted to stress out that my code works in local env, in debug and release mode.
Also, when I put code on my server, I can execute code via powershell (./svcWorker.exe) or just double clicking in the folder on svcWorker.exe

Also, I checked that I have .net core framework and I have among the others also 5.0.5 framework.

What else could I try?

Comment: Hi @Stefan0309, your code preview does not work,please share the correct link. Besides, what is your error message?

Comment: @Rena sorry, I updated link, you can try now.